# How to place an IF condition in a trigger to calculate a value for a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ia_att` decimal(3,2) NULL,
  `t1` decimal(3,2) NULL,
  `t2` decimal(3,2) NULL,
  `t3` decimal(3,2) NULL,
  `ia_tot` decimal(3,2) NULL,
  .....
  .....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

In the above table there are many more number of colums, But i am fixed in caluclating of these columns the calculation i require is, that

- if ia_att column is grater than >95 then value = 5 ;
- if it is >80 <95 then value = 4;
- if it is >75 <80 then value = 3;
- if it is >60 <75 then value = 2;
  -if it is <60 then  value = 0;

and i have to take 2 best values out of the three colums t1,t2,t3.
and sum those two large values and divide it by "2". and add the value from ia_att and the result should be placed in ia_tot column."All the above said calculation should happen each and every time a  new entry comes to those columns."
Example conside that

```
ia_att = 72 
t1 = 18
t2 = 15
t3 = 20
then {[(18 + 20)/2] + 2} = 21;
```

18 and 20 are two large values from t1 ,t2 ,t3 2 is from ia_att.

PLZ help me for the above calulation in mysql.

Comment: Why all of your columns that should contain numeric data are of type `VARCHAR(5)`???

Comment: ok i will change it to decimal pls help me in the equations side

Comment: What do you mean by *...take 2 best values out of the three colums t1,t2,t3*? Two largest values or something else?

Comment: two largest values only that is if t1 =23 t2=21 t3 =24 i have to take 23+24 and divide it by 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_test
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.ia_tot = 
     (NEW.t1 + NEW.t2 + NEW.t3 -
      LEAST(NEW.t1, NEW.t2, NEW.t3)) / 2 + 
     CASE 
       WHEN NEW.ia_att > 95 THEN 5
       WHEN NEW.ia_att BETWEEN 81 AND 95 THEN 4
       WHEN NEW.ia_att BETWEEN 76 AND 80 THEN 3
       WHEN NEW.ia_att BETWEEN 61 AND 75 THEN 2
       WHEN NEW.ia_att < 60 THEN 2
     END;
```

The result of issuing

```
INSERT INTO test (ia_att, t1, t2, t3) VALUES (72, 18, 15, 20);
```

will be

```
| ID | IA_ATT | T1 | T2 | T3 | IA_TOT |
|----|--------|----|----|----|--------|
|  1 |     72 | 18 | 15 | 20 |     21 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dba2c/1)** demo

Comment: what if i have seven coloums of ia_tot_1 and so on can i place trigger to all those coloums in the same statement

Comment: @user2774977 [`SET` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html) allows you to assign values to as many variables as you like separating assignments by comma. Now in a trigger `NEW.column_name` is just a variable that represents column value of row being processed by that trigger.